# Remove the permission to create a report in the public report folder

Tags: reporting, profile, permission-sets

Hello,

An user has a profile and a permission set.
In the profile, the user has no one checkbox related to reports or dashboards checked and in the permission set, only the checkbox "Create and Customize Reports" checked.

The point is that the user is able to create a report in the public reports folder.

The need is to allow to the user to be able to create and read private reports (when it is shared with him) but to be able only to read reports in the public report folder (not to be able to create).

What is wrong with the settings please?

Thanks

Comment: The "Manage Reports in Public Folders" permission on profile level should handle that ? 
Is it unchecked ?

Comment: Yes, it is unchecked, it is why I don't understand.

Comment: Recommend seeing [User with report folder "View" access can save and edit reports](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000333874&type=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we can not restrict the users from saving the report in Public Folder. This is the current working as-designed behavior.  This means that as long as the profile has "Create and Customize Reports" permission to create a report, they can still save a report on Public Report folder.This means that as long as the profile has "Create and Customize Reports" permission, they can still save a report on Public Report folder.

The only way to prevent a user to save a report in a public folder is to remove the permission to create a report. However, this will not meet your requirement since your users need to create a report.

There is also an Idea to have this functionality implemented: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdfhLUAR/manage-access-and-sharing-rules-on-unfiled-public-reports

Comment: Thank you for the information.